# Using jquery to hide and show tables with option values

Tags: jquery

I've been using this bit of jquery code on my website:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $('#tablets').change(function() {
    $('#LeapPad 2 Explorer,#VTech InnoTab 2').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});

});
```

But it doesn't seem to be working?

My website link is: http://mykidstablet.co.uk

Comment: can you post some HTML for the relevant tags? What is the 2 in your selectors?

Comment: `#LeapPad 2 Explorer` is an element ID? If yes, then you can't have space in the `ID`.

Comment: it will probably be easier to view the source on my homepage rather than copying all of the html :)

Comment: even if I remove the space in the id it still doesn't work

Comment: First, Muthu is right, no spaces in the ID. Second, what exactly are you trying to show() ? The tables are already visible.

Comment: I'm trying to show only one table, when selected by the option menu

Comment: Check my answer below...Hide the tables by class, not ID, and show by ID (which cannot have spaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dealing with jQuery in a "noconflict" style, as such your '$' is not defined in there, change your function to read:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#tablets').change(function() {
       $('#LeapPad 2 Explorer,#VTech InnoTab 2').hide();
       $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  })
});
```

the ready function will be passed the jQuery instance in use.

**NOTE** removed previously added comments with regard to IDs. See other answers for specifics.

Comment: When I'm using this, when I select an option value it is removing both my tables

Comment: Ah ok - I might have missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use spaces, the reason for this is simple, space character is not a valid for ID attribute.

```
ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of   letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this.$ comes back as undefined on your website. I'm not sure why, try replacing $ with jQuery like you did at the top so...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#tablets').change(function() {
jQuery('#LeapPad 2 Explorer,#VTech InnoTab 2').hide();
jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).show();
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Eliminate the spaces in the Select "Value" and the Table Id's , Also, Instead of hiding by ID, hide the class attached to the item tables**

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tablets').change(function() {
        $('.stock-list').hide(); // Hide all Item Tables
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

**Select Html**

```
<select id="tablets">
<option value="LeapPad2Explorer">LeapPad 2 Explorer</option>
<option value="LeapPadExplorer">LeapPad Explorer</option>
<option value="VTechInnoTab2">VTech InnoTab 2</option>
<option value="HelloKitty7inchTablet">Hello Kitty 7 inch Tablet</option>
<option value="KurioKidsTabletwithAndroid4.0">Kurio Kids Tablet with Android 4.0</option>
<option value="Tabeo7inchKidsTablet">Tabeo 7 inch Kids Tablet</option>
</select>
```

**Table Html**

```
<table class="stock-list tablesorter" id="LeapPad2Explorer" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
///Table Content
</table>

<table class="stock-list tablesorter" id="VTechInnoTab2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
///Table Content
</table>
```